# Birthday problem with a twist

Tags: probability

Two of my facebook friends had their birthdays on the same day

The first guy's name was "Wael Toujeni"

The second guy's name was "Wael Jeni"

How do I calculate the probability of this event happening?

The event: two of your facebook friends have the same birthday, and have similar names except an n characters difference in their last names.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd be able using combinatorics. There may be other factors to consider for example language. Richards and RichardSON  may be common English surnames but how that bears out with other languages I don't know.

Comment: Since the event happened, we can now say that its probability is 1.

Comment: @Karl Suppose we could know for each facebooker how many friends he has, how many of them share birthdays, how many of them share birthdays. How would we calculate the probability?

Comment: @GerryMyerson since the probability is 1, can you tell me who of your friends share birthdays and have similar names? I know you must have at least two of them.

Comment: The event you described happened to you, so the probability of the event is 1. The event hasn't happened to me, and, besides, it's none of your business who my friends are.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I didn't mean to upset you, by the way I just trew two dices and they came 6 and 6, now I know that probability is 1 since it happened to me.

Comment: Yes, Ben, *after the fact* the probability is 1.

Answer (score 0):

We all know how to solve the birthday problem right?

Let's take a look at the other problem now. Assuming we can get all the data we need, we can devise two strategies:

1 - If we wanted to know the probability that anybody can witness such an unsual event we can use the law of conditional probability: $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

Where A: the two people have similar names, and B: the two people have a friend in common.

Of course we use conditional probability because the events are not independent, for reason of family ties or localization people who have similar names are more likely to have friends in common than regular people.

2 - The other approach is using machine learning techniques.

Assume we have collected many features(friend count, country, age, etc.), then applied a given learning algorithm to determine, for a given facebooker how many of his friends have similar names.

That's it, we compute: $p(n) = 1 - \frac{_{365}P_n}{365^n}$

But wait a minute, couldn't we just check, for that facebooker, that event occured?

Well yes. We then compute the probability and tell him: Look.. an event with this tiny probability happened to you.